# IBM Cloud Object Storage, cannot modify object ACL permissions

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, storage, object-storage

Using the Node.js SDK for IBM Cloud Object Storage, I can successfully create new objects with the `public-read` ACL setting.

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream, ACL: 'public-read`};
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

Files can be accessed without authentication once uploaded.

However, once a file is uploaded, trying to update the ACL permissions to turn a `private` file to `public-read` fails with `Access Denied` errors.

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream, ACL: 'public-read`};
s3.putObjectAcl(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
})
```

This is the error message return in the response.

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
    "errorType": "Error"
}
```

Retrieving the ACL using `getObjectAcl` also fails with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication credentials must have the `Manager` role to access and modify ACLs for existing objects.

Check the role assigned to your service identifier. If you can create new objects, you may have the `Writer` role rather than the `Manager`.

More details on the permissions model can be found here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/iam/buckets.html#bucket-permissions